# Show/select code being used while program is running in VS2013

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am currently new to VS2013 and don't know if this is even a realistic expectation. Is it possible that while running a desktop application (non console) within VS, that it show you the code that is being executed, side by side with the application? An example might be to select a button or menu on the application's screen and then see the code used for that button on a separate window. The goal is to find out the code location of the features being run.

Comment: Why not just debug the program?

Comment: You mean other than by using the debugger and breakpoints? Or just by clicking on the button and then looking at the Events tab in Properties to see the code attached to it's Click handler while developing?

Comment: I don't think you can have VS highlight code live, but you can set a breakpoint in a click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .NET applications you can use the [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool (commercial, developed by me) to show currently executed methods.

Comment: This looks about like what I was wanting. Are there any limitations such as VS versions or program size?

Comment: All non-express VS editions are supported for any program size.